# Making a Facebook Graph API call which specified multiple posiIds

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way with the facebook graph api that I can query the posts api or feeds api using multiple postids in one call?
The below doesn't work, but does something similar exist?
{PageId}/posts?ids={PostId1},{PostId2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. If you have two post_ids, for example `21898300328_10154059491180329` and `8062627951_10153779074657952`, the call would look like

```
/?ids=21898300328_10154059491180329,8062627951_10153779074657952&fields=id,from,message
```

which results in

```
{
  "21898300328_10154059491180329": {
    "id": "21898300328_10154059491180329",
    "from": {
      "name": "BuzzFeed",
      "id": "21898300328"
    },
    "message": ""Your teen films ruined us, America.""
  },
  "8062627951_10153779074657952": {
    "id": "8062627951_10153779074657952",
    "from": {
      "name": "TechCrunch",
      "id": "8062627951"
    },
    "message": "Sprinklr sure is making a lot of acquisitions"
  },
}
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#fields

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated. Just what I needed